Calculating net survival: should one use the relsurv or popEpi package?
The Pohar Perme estimator was proposed in 2012 as an unbiased estimator of net survival, initially in cancer studies. Net survival estimates the survival compared to the background mortality expected in the absence of a cancer diagnosis, and has advantages, especially in international comparisons, compared to other measures such as standard relative survival. That team then created the relsurv R package to allow the easy calculation of net survival.
The popEpi package also provides, via its survtab function, for calculating survival using the Pohar Perme method.
Are there methodological differences between these packages for the specific purpose of assessing net survival?

Questions solely about how software works are
off-topic
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you
understand the statistical concepts involved, the
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least
easy to get from the documentation.

I’ve re-phrased to emphasise that the question is about differences or consistency in the methodological approach taken by the two sets of authors. I’m not questioning how to use the software - that is clear from the respective documentation.
